# Magento2 How To Add Visual Swatch in product option. as a Customizable Options Type

Tags: magento2, custom-options, visualswatch

[image]

Same as per Image i want to add option...So how can i add or devlope a Module ?

Comment: Check this link and you can customize.
https://devhooks.in/blog/magento2-how-to-add-custom-input-type-in-custom-option